# If Java is pass-by-value, then why can we change the properties of objects in methods?

Tags: java

This gif was retrieved from https://blog.penjee.com/passing-by-value-vs-by-reference-java-graphical/

[image: An animation depicting pass-by-value vs pass-by-references]

Maybe I'm terribly misunderstanding this, but please bear with me.

According to my understanding, when we define a variable in java, we are essentially creating a pointer to that object that is created. i.e.

```
Object objPointer = new Object();
```

Here objPointer is reference to the Object that was created, not the object itself. And when we use this object as an argument in a method:

```
void foo(Object newPointer){
    //newPointer points to a copy of the Object objPointer pointed to.
}

foo(objPointer);
```

The formal argument newPointer is pointer to a copy of the value of the object that is passed as an argument. This is why swap methods don't work in java.

But my question is this:
If the formal argument only points to a copy of the original object, then why can we change the values of the properties of that object? i.e.

```
class Object{
   int var = 0; //default value of 0
   void setVar(int newValue){
      this.var = newValue;
   }
}

void foo(Object newPointer){
    newPointer.setVar(1); 
}

Object objPointer = new Object();
//The Object objPointer points to has a var value of 0 as default.

foo(objPointer);

/*
       After foo is called, the var value of objPointer has changed to 1
     although the setVar method should only change the value of var for the copy 
     of that object that newPointer points to.
*/
```

I hope what I'm asking makes sense, the gif I found kind of illustrates what I'm saying: How are the properties of the cup Object changed, if fillCup only changes the properties of the copy?

Comment: The copy is the value, which is the pointer to the same reference (i.e. there aren't two instances).

Comment: The "pointer" is the value being passed.  There's still only one instance of `Object` on the heap, but there's a copy of the "pointer" made in the stack.

Comment: The pointer gets copied, but both pointers point to the same object.

Comment: Since you can only pass pointers or primary values in java, you will never copy objects when calling function s.

Comment: _References are passed by value._

Comment: The test isn't whether the object pointed to by the pointer can be changed, @RahulChowdhury, but whether the caller sees a change if the parameter is reassigned. So not `newPointer.setVar(1);` but `newPointer = new Pointer();`. You have to use the correct test. The test you posted only shows pass-by-value of pointers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you pass the `objPointer` *reference* to the `foo` method, the `foo` method obtains a copy of the object *reference*, through this *reference*, it can access or mutate the parameter object. However, if you change the object to which the parameter refers i.e. a new object then this will *not* affect the initial object that was first passed in.

Answer (score 0):

You're passing the copy of the reference which still points to the same object in the memory. You are not passing a `new object`. You are passing the reference to the `objPointer` that you created at line: `Object objPointer = new Object();`