# Although I can change properties of my custom object in methods, I cannot change properties of Vector3 (Unity, C#)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, oop

I am a Java developer, Java is pass-by-value but we change change properties of an object in method. I cannot explain it well but here is a link:
[If Java is pass-by-value, then why can we change the properties of objects in methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43826922/if-java-is-pass-by-value-then-why-can-we-change-the-properties-of-objects-in-me)
I am also developing games in Unity with C#. I wonder that the above situation can also be valid in C# language. I tried it and yes, it is valid and it is same. While trying, I defined a class myself and tried to change its property. After that, I tried with Vector3 and it did not work.

```
void Start()
{
    Vector3 v = new Vector3(0,0,0);
    setVector3(v);
    Debug.Log(v);
}

void setVector3(Vector3 v)
{
    v.x = 5;
}
```

Although we can change properties of an object in methods in C#, why cannot I change x property of Vector3 (x property can be setted like that, it is not the problem)?

Comment: Please read: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) --- Please read: [Can I ask only one question per post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222735/can-i-ask-only-one-question-per-post) --- How is the question related to java?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because `Vector3` [is a `struct`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.html), not a `class`.  Which makes it a value-type (as opposed to a reference-type).  Similar to an `int` for example.

So in your `setVector3` method you are modifying a *copy* of the `Vector3` object local only to that method.

You can explicitly [pass it by reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/ref):

```
void setVector3(ref Vector3 v)
```

This would tell the compiler to use the same instance of the value-type in the method frame as it used in the calling frame.

If you passed in a *reference-type* (something defined as a `class`) then you would observe by default the behavior you are expecting.  That object would exist on the heap and would be the same object reference throughout the stack.